# Use JS within PHP to change a class property

Tags: javascript, php, hide

I have a mainly php form with a radio button (rb) controlled question at one point.  The idea is that, if the rb is checked 'yes', then the rest of the question will show.  To initialy hide the rest, I added a css class to that div, with opacity: 0;  I am using js to set the opacity to 1 when the rb is checked 'yes'.

I dont know PHP, so unsurprisingly I'm struggling with the syntax (I think).
This now Loads OK, but is not working yet ... I will need to show the whole div for this

```
<div id="menopausal" class = "row">   
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 "> 
            <label id="mps" for="mps">Are you menopausal?</label><br />  
            <?php $is_menopausal = (isset($questionnaire['is_menopausal']) && $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] == "1"); ?>
            <label class="radio-wrap"><input id="mpsY" for="mpsY" type="radio" name="is_menopausal" value="1"
                <?php echo $is_menopausal ? " checked " : ""  ?> /> 
                <?php if ($is_menopausal): ?>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("menopausal").getElementsByClassName("reveal-when-active").style.opacity = 1.0;
                    </script>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <span>Yes</span>
            </label>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
            <label class="radio-wrap"><input id="mpsN" for="mpsX" type="radio" value="0" name="is_menopausal"
                <?php if (isset($questionnaire['is_menopausal']) && $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] == "0") echo " checked "; ?> /><span>No</span>
            </label>
    </div>                  
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active"> 
            <label>Age of onset:</label>
            <input type="text"  name="age_of_mp_onset" style="width: 50%;"
                value="<?php if (isset($questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset'])) echo $questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset']; ?>"
                class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active"> 
            <label>Date of last period:</label>
            <input type="text" name="date_of_last_period" style="width: 50%;"
                value="<?php if (isset($questionnaire['date_of_last_period'])) echo $questionnaire['date_of_last_period']; ?>"
                class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript (now with class) isn't changing the reveal-when-active... opacity.  To me it looks like it should work?

Comment: `document.getElementById("menopausal")` is looking for an id that doesn't exist. Also note that `for` goes on labels not on `<input>` elements. It is used to match the label to the input

Comment: `if ( ... ) echo " checked "; {` appears to be invalid syntax. You will need to move the `echo " checked "` into the brackets, and then move your `script` section out of the `<input>` html element attributes. https://jsfiddle.net/L6abx9w4/

Comment: Please assume that id exists :-)
I'd missed the input tag.  Sorry, didn't understand your If, so what I've got now is as edited above - still doesn't work.
Error in console is: GET https://.......  500

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You don't need JavaSript to show or hide HTML Elements from php. It's just a matter of adding (or not adding) a class to an element and hide or unhide from a Style Sheet.

[Link to tan explanation on how to use the ternary operator.](https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6)

And this is how you do it.

```
<?php
//First we determine the state of the "is_menopausal" condition and, as you'll use it in many places,
//save the state in a variable
$is_menopausal = ( isset( $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] ) && $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] == 1 );
?>


<div id="menopausal" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ">
        <label id="mps" for="mps">Are you menopausal?</label><br/>
        <label class="radio-wrap">
            <input id="mpsY" for="mpsY" type="radio" name="is_menopausal" value="1"
                <?php echo $is_menopausal ? " checked " : "" ?> />
            <span>Yes</span>
        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-wrap">
            <input id="mpsN" for="mpsX" type="radio" value="0" name="is_menopausal"
                <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "" : " checked " ?> />
            <span>No</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "active" : "" ?>">
        <label>Age of onset:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age_of_mp_onset" style="width: 50%;"
               value="<?php echo isset( $questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset'] ) ? $questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset'] : "" ?>"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "active" : "" ?>">
        <label>Date of last period:</label>
        <input type="text" name="date_of_last_period" style="width: 50%;"
               value="<?php echo isset( $questionnaire['date_of_last_period'] ) ? $questionnaire['date_of_last_period'] : "" ?>"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This should be in a separate css style sheet -->
<style type="text/css">
    .reveal-when-active{
        display: none;
    }
    .reveal-when-active.active {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

PHP only prints a class in some of the HTML elements if the `$is_menopausal` conditions is true and from a Style Sheet we determine if that class is to be shown or not.

But if you insist in using JavaScript you do can do it like this.

```
<?php
//First you determine the state of the "is_menopausal" condition and, as you'll use it in many places,
//save the state in a variable
$is_menopausal = ( isset( $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] ) && $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] == 1 );
?>


<div id="menopausal" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ">
        <label id="mps" for="mps">Are you menopausal?</label><br/>
        <label class="radio-wrap">
            <input id="mpsY" for="mpsY" type="radio" name="is_menopausal" value="1"
                <?php echo $is_menopausal ? " checked " : "" ?> />
            <span>Yes</span>
        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-wrap">
            <input id="mpsN" for="mpsX" type="radio" value="0" name="is_menopausal"
                <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "" : " checked " ?> />
            <span>No</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "active" : "" ?>">
        <label>Age of onset:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age_of_mp_onset" style="width: 50%;"
               value="<?php echo isset( $questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset'] ) ? $questionnaire['age_of_mp_onset'] : "" ?>"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3  reveal-when-active <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "active" : "" ?>">
        <label>Date of last period:</label>
        <input type="text" name="date_of_last_period" style="width: 50%;"
               value="<?php echo isset( $questionnaire['date_of_last_period'] ) ? $questionnaire['date_of_last_period'] : "" ?>"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This should be in a separate css file-->
<style type="text/css" >
    .reveal-when-active{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<!-- This could be in a separate js file-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){
        let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('reveal-when-active active');
        for(let element of elements) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
    })();

</script>
```

Javascript shows elements (in this case hidden by default) that are both of class `reveal-when-active` and `active`.

You should be careful with indentation and proper HTML tags opening-closing. Also you don't need to use a full conditional structure when you can use the ternary operator inside the `input` tag.

This is how I would do it. You'll see that the code is much clearer.

```
<?php
    $is_menopausal = (isset($questionnaire['is_menopausal']) && $questionnaire['is_menopausal'] == "1");
?>
<label class="radio-wrap" for="mpsY">
    <input id="mpsY"
           type="radio" value="1" name="is_menopausal" <?php echo $is_menopausal ? "checked" : ""  ?> >
    <?php if ($is_menopausal): ?>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("menopausal").style.opacity = 1.0;
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span>Yes</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks @David, that loads now - but pls explain the  : ""   after the "checked"

Comment: Loads, but not wqorking yet ... I will need the whole div for this ...

Comment: Looks like the js isn't being called?  ( I added an alert within the <script> to check)

Comment: @Ognik Ok. If I understand properly what you need is to show the divs with class `eveal-when-active` if the questionnaire value `is_menopausal` is true. Right? You don't need JavaScript in that case.

Comment: @Ognik check my answer again. I edited it with some new code.

Comment: Thanks @David, I underrstand ternary, and it clarifies a concern I hadn't got to yet - the " checked " wasn't set correctly.

I'm good to stay with php.  Note, I am using opacity 'cos I want to keep the space, so I copied your code as is, except for the css.

It didn't work, I looked in dev tools and .active wasn't set after checking Yes.
I added .active manually in dev tools and that worked as expected, so the php to change the class doesn't seem to work?  I'll keep fiddling, but would appreciate your reaction?

Comment: is $is_menopausal a listener type function?  Doesn't it need to be a listener to know whcih button was checked?

Comment: Thinking more, the earlier JS also didn't trigger - also after   <?php if ($is_menopausal): ?>  - so its probably the same reason the php to change class is not triggering?

Comment: It seems I've lost @David, does anybody else have an idea why that php to change the class is not triggering?